# convert an object to serde_json::Value without serializing and deserializing

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have this struct that has a field containing type `Option<serde_json::Value>`

I want to be able to store any object( i.e. object created by any struct) in that field. The current approach I'm using is to first convert the object to JSON string (using `serde_json::to_string`) and then convert it again to `serde_json::Value` using `serde_json::from_str` .

I'm doing this so that I can send different kinds of JSON requests with arbitrary data.

So, is there a way to convert any serde-serializable object to `serde_json::Value` without doing a `serde_json::to_string` and `serde_json::from_str` ?
If I'm going the wrong way with this, please suggest a better one, ty!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`serde_json::value::to_value()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.66/serde_json/value/fn.to_value.html) specifically for this:

```
pub fn to_value<T>(value: T) -> Result<Value, Error>  where
    T: Serialize,
```

That is, `to_value` takes any `T` that is `Serialize` and gives you a `Value` or an error (in case serialization fails).